# body mesh clips through armor mesh, mesh not taking to bones

Tags: animation, mesh, rigging

Ok so im a big noob on blender and i imagine this has to do with weights but i feel ive gone through every avenue to solve this issue and cant find anything on this. I have a mesh Ive tried to attach armor to, and it takes but the body under the armor acts like the armor doesnt contain it. heres an image on UE4 of what i mean.[image]

As you can see the shoulder just sticks out, in reality (so to speak) the armor should bend with it like rubber. Now i didnt make the armature myself i imported the mesh into mixamo and then opened it in blender. originally mixamo didnt like the armor being in the mesh and would curve its shoulder wings of the armor with the arm movement. To fix this i removed the armor and re imported back into mixamo. it worked great! now im putting the armor back and the results are better but now im getting the body mesh peering through the armor like shown in the image above.

In blender i append my armor. then i joined it to the body mesh. if you look at the outliner in the pictures below you can see what was done.
[image]

[image]

so im able to move the mesh in pose mode and it wont effect the shoulders which is good, and the fbx shows the armor on him in ue4 but i cant figure out how to contain the body in the armor, id also like to keep my bones if possible, i want to use the mixamo animations. If i could just get some assistance or even a nudge in the right direction, id appreciate any help i can get. if you need more i can upload the blender file just ask.

thank you to whoever reads this :)

Comment: You need to weight the armor to the bones.  The quickest (not best) way to do this is with a data transfer modifier, transferring vertex groups, probably on the basis of nearest face interpolated.  From your pic, you may need to position the armor correctly first.  If you weren't doing it for UE, you could get a good approximation via a surface deform modifier instead.

Comment: Thanks for the response Nathan. I will look into the data transfer modifier, however like I said I'm a noob and i have no idea how to use that modifier lol, also I realize in blender the position of the armor looks strange, if I select the body mesh and change to edit mode the body changes position to where the armor is in the picture, if that is an issue i would like to know how to fix it. Other than that i figured it was positioned correctly. I could be wrong :)

Comment: It's fine to be a noob.  Maybe you've bitten off more than you can chew.  For right now, the important thing is that you start learning about weights and vertex groups, which are what you need to make the armor move correctly.

Comment: Ok I bought the course for blender on udemy. I'm going to look up weights and vertex groups there now and see what I can figure out. Thanks alot

Comment: Oh actually one last question. If I make a vertex group in one mesh (the armor) and join it to the other mesh (body) to make one mesh, will the vertex group in the armor still exist?

Comment: "Oh actually one last question. If I make a vertex group in one mesh (the armor) and join it to the other mesh (body) to make one mesh, will the vertex group in the armor still exist?" Yes.